# Restart failed XCTests in Fastlane

Tags: swift, xctest, fastlane

I am trying to restart the tests that failed through Fastlane.

Here is the script I am using without much success.
The part that is not working is find_failed_tests. For some reason the failed tests are not in the junit report.

```
@test_retries = 3
TARGET_DEVICES = ["iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"]

lane :testRetry do
    testNames = ["Example_UITests/SearchForm_TestA", "Example_UITests/SearchForm_TestB"]
    UI.message("Testing only tests: #{testNames}")

    begin
        scan(
        scheme: "Example",
        devices: TARGET_DEVICES,
        output_types: 'junit',
        fail_build: false,
            only_testing: testNames,
            clean: true
      )
    rescue

       while @test_retries > 0
         failed_tests = find_failed_tests
         UI.message("Retrying failed tests: #{failed_tests}")

       break if failed_tests.empty?
       @test_retries -= 1
       scan(
             scheme: "Example",
         devices: TARGET_DEVICES,
         output_types: 'junit',
         fail_build: @test_retries.zero?,
         only_testing: failed_tests,
             clean: true
       )
        end
    end
end

def find_failed_tests
    report = File.open('test_output/report.junit') { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
    suite_name = report.xpath('testsuites/@name').to_s.split('.')[0]

    test_cases = report.xpath('//testcase')

    only_testing = []
    test_cases.each do |test_case|

        next if test_case.xpath('failure').empty?

    test_class = test_case.xpath('@classname').to_s.split('.')[1]
    test_name = test_case.xpath('@name')
    only_testing << "#{suite_name}/#{test_class}/#{test_name}"
    end

    only_testing.join(',')
end
```

The issue that I am having is the failed tests are not being reported in junit.
The report.xml just shows the passed tests.

Comment: First, I'd like to suggest using my plugin's action `multi_scan`. You can tell it how many times to retry "failed" tests. You need not write your own version.
https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/fastlane-plugin-test_center#features

Comment: However, that doesn't answer your question. I'd suggest posting your console log that displays that tests actually failed. Are you certain tests are actually failing? Is a test run crashing?

Comment: Also, you've confirmed that your `find_failed_tests` method is correct? Have you looked at the `report.xml` file to confirm that there are *zero* failed tests.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson I have previously tried your plugin but I had a few issues with it:
- I keep getting: "Is the Build Setting, `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` enabled for the test target". No tests found.

In my setup I also need to be able to use "only_testing:" and it doesn't seem to work.

The option "skip_testing:" is also ignored. I am ignoring all the unit tests but they are still trying to be run until I got the error ("no tests") described above.

Checking the targets I can see "ENABLE_TESTABILITY" is enabled so I am not sure why this pops up.

Comment: And yes, the bit that is failing in my implementation is find_failed_tests. Feels like the failed tests are not being "recorded" in the junit report.

Comment: Hi Joao. `only_testing` definitely should work in that it will pass down the tests to the underlying `scan` tool. I'd love to fix that issue if it still happens for you if you'd be willing to open an Issue.

Comment: With regards to `ENABLE_TESTABILITY`, this was added because people were trying to run `multi_scan` with the "Enable Testability" setting was set to "NO" for the selected configuration. This meant that the tests were not in the actual xctest binary -- that may even be the cause of the problem you are working with.

I'd ask that you confirm that that setting is set to "YES" before using `multi_scan`. See [this](https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/fastlane-plugin-test_center/issues/86#issuecomment-440606111) for an example.